# Database tables show in listing, but system tells me they do not exist

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, workbench

I had been working with MySQL in Windows/XAMPP through Workbench and phpMyadmin.  There were 10 databases created and I still see them in both programs.  I was able to use them all for many weeks, but today, half of them are giving the "error code 1146 - table does not exist".

In Workbench, when I execute "SHOW DATABASES;" and "SHOW TABLES IN xxxDB;", they give a result as expected.  But when I execute "SELECT * FROM xxxx;", it gives me that 1146 error.

In phpMyAdmin, I also see the db's and tables, but when I click on the tables, I get the same error.

I noticed that the ones that are OK have the .frm and .ibd files.  The problem ones are missing the .ibd files.

What could be happening here and how did it happen?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I fear your database might have become corrupt.

Have you tried running `mysqlcheck -u mysql_username -p database_name`?

(I believe it's default location on windows is `C:\Program Files\ApacheFriends.org\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqlcheck.exe`)

If that still gives you the same error, I'm affraid there not much else to do besides restoring a backup.

Databases can become corrupt for many reasons, ie. when the system shuts down, crashes or loses power while something is being written.

Best of luck!